# Changing the z-index (order) of shapes and connections of Telerik RadDiagram

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-ajax, raddiagram

I am using Telerik RadDiagram for building a diagram. The gray lines are over the shapes (requirements, development etc) in my diagram. Is there any way to put them behind the shapes?

[image]

```
// ... getting ready the shape objects ...

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < monthCount + 1; i++, j = j + 2)
{
    // ... getting ready the shape and connection objects ...

    RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(shapeForLines[j]);
    RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(shapeForLines[j + 1]);
    RadDiagram1.ConnectionsCollection.Add(monthLine[i]);
    RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(labelMonth[i]);
}


for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (i < 6) { RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(shape[i]); }
    if (i < 7) { RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(label[i]); }
}
```

Comment: This is totally a guess, as I do not use the diagram, but have you tried changing the event in which you create the lines? I'm assuming that if they are created after the shapes are created they will have a higher z-index.

Comment: You mean adding lines after adding the shapes? It's a good guess but it doesn't work. No matter I add lines before or after the shapes, lines are always on top of shapes. For some reason, objects in ConnestionsCollection always have the priority.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: while the Default.aspx loads a Java-Script-Method is called and there the Connections are brought to back:

```
function diagram_load(sender) {
    diagram = sender.get_kendoWidget();
    //.....
    diagram.toFront(diagram.Shape);
    diagram.toBack(diagram.connections);
} // diagram_load(sender)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set `ZIndex` property while you create shapes. i set this in WinForms, maybe you can find it too